# string replace using a regex

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have a string after Json.stringify in javascript using node. I wanted to replace the text in the string which starts with 'ab' then followed by some numbers(atleast one digit), with 'ab^^^^^^' where the number of '^' s should be equal to the number of digits after ab. The text starting with ab can occur atleast once, In this example it occurs twice. I need help in regex and replacing the string

string - in this, text starting with ab occurs twice.

```
var str = JSON.stringify({"abc":{"idcardno":"ertyuiop","form":{"somestring":"This string:\n- can have multiple \nab12345ab5677\n","flag":"true","flag2":"false"},"anothertext":"samplestring","numbetstr":"7"}});
```

after the regex replace it should be like this

```
{"abc":{"idcardno":"ertyuiop","form":{"somestring":"This string:\n- can have multiple \na^^^^^ab^^^^\n","flag":"true","flag2":"false"},"anothertext":"samplestring","numbetstr":"7"}}
```

**Edit**

As per the post below the below will be the contents of obj.abc.form.string, coming in multiple lines. How do I do the regex(above mentioned) replace of this object?

```
This string:
- can have multiple 
ab12345ab56778
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't process stringifed JSON with regexp. Process the JavaScript object itself, then stringify. In your case, assuming `obj` is the input:

```
obj.abc.form.somestring = transform(obj.abc.form.somestring);
str = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

where `transform` is a regexp/replace making the transformation you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot... Could you please help me in the regex, the string obj.abc.form.somestring comes in multiple lines - edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

@torazaburo is right, it's a bad practice to manipulate JSON directly.  Once you get ahold of the string in obj.abc.form.somestring, though, you can use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), passing a function:

```
str.replace(/ab\d+/g, function(match) {return match.replace(/\d/g,'^')})
```

Comment: Thanks you all...... It worked. Is there any reason it is a bad practice to manipulate on the string from stringify directly?

Comment: *Is there any reason it is a bad practice*. 1. You don't need to. 2. You could break the JSON.